# Is it possible to embed/stream/project the live image of a native Windows window into a webpage?

Tags: node.js

In the new Microsoft Flight Simulator you can pop different cockpit displays out into their own external windows, like this:

[image]

However, none of the buttons needed to interact with the displays get "popped out" as well.

I'd like to build a web app that can embed (the continuously updating image of) one of these windows that I can surround with buttons, etc, for interaction to have, say, running on a tablet next to you.

My question is, is it possible with Node to embed the continuously updating image of a native Windows window within a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon the Screen Capture API.  This is what I was looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API